# How to subtract mean between groups in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, partition

I have a table like:

| AVG_AMOUNT | WAS_MEMBER | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200.00 | True | 2018 |
| 100.00 | False | 2018 |
| 20.00 | True | 2019 |
| 300.00 | False | 2019 |
| 400.00 | True | 2020 |
| 10.00 | False | 2020 |

And I want a table like:

| DIFF_AVG_AMOUNT | YEAR |
| --- | --- |
| 100.00 | 2018 |
| -280.00 | 2019 |
| 390.00 | 2020 |

How can I get a difference of means based on membership for each year? Probably uses a partition over but not sure how to use difference with a partition.

Comment: What is your DBMS? You should always tag SQL questions with the DBMS you are using, because the answer may depend on that. Are True and False strings or boolean values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation containing `SUM()` such as

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN was_member='True'  THEN   avg_amount 
                WHEN was_member='False' THEN - avg_amount END) AS diff_avg_amount, 
       year
  FROM tab
 GROUP BY year
 ORDER BY year
```

Comment: Or just `SUM(CASE WHEN was_member = 'True' THEN avg_amount ELSE - avg_amount END)` :-) And I would add an `ORDER BY` clause to get the result ordered by year.